# Sorting view after month but not after year

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm struggling with views and could use help. I'm trying to generate a dropdown to select a specific month in a date list. My problem is the following. I can't select only month, always have to select year and month. But if I do so, my dropdown will only work for this year, not for every upcoming one.

What I've done so far: Created a grouped filter and within it "between" statements. But those only work with year and month. I want my dropdown to work automatically for every year.

Anyone has a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

mate, I think you try to filter date between start & end date, or tow date ..

to do that you can use a very nice module ..[Filter date](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_between_dates_filter)
this module will give you option to select year, month, day .. all of them ..etc, & filter dependance by your select ...

Comment: Sorry, I can't see what this is doing what the standard isn't. To make it clearer. I have a list with dates from january to december for 2014 and 2015. When i select "august" in a dropdown, i want to see all dates in august in 2014 and 2015. But if I add dates for 2016 later on I want that my dropdown is still working and shows all dates for all 3 years.